# Xpath simple problem

Tags: xml, xpath

The following code works for saved XML file but won't parse HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

xml=loadXMLDoc("test.html");
path="div[@id='aa']/span[@class]//a[@href]"
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
var nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);

for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
  {
  document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br />");
  }
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();

while (result)
  {
  document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br />");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The test.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="aa">
        <span class="bb">
            <a href="http://google.com">link 1</a>
        </span>
    </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Now it's valid HTML but again parsing doesn't work

Comment: The code sample you have provided is not valid HTML (or XHTML).

Comment: Everything is open and closed as it should be. Why not valid?

Comment: You've fixed some errors between my last comment and your last comment, but there are still errors there. **[use a validator](http://validator.w3.org/)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" but I suspect you will need to replace your HTML with [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) if you want use an XML parser. Normal HTML doesn't obey all the rules of XML (e.g. you can have unclosed tags such as `<br>`).

Comment: Added <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
but it won't parse